# Flux + React.js Login/register flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, registration, reactjs-flux, flux

I'm looking for some guide how to organize best login/registration flow in my Flux+React.js app.

What I have is a REST API which while registration/login returns `access_token` which I can use in all other requests to get user data. Very basic.

I'm using ReactRouter and what comes to mind firstly is to use 2 `<Route>`'s for login pages and for secured ones, e.g.:

```
<Route name="app" handler={AppHandler} path="/">
  <Route name="auth" handler={AuthHandler}>
    <Route name="login" handler={RegisterHandler} path="/register"/>
    <Route name="register" handler={LoginHandler} path="/login"/>
  </Route>
  <Route name="secured" handler={EnsureAuthHandler}>
    <Route name="dashboard" handler={Dashboard} />
  </Route>
  <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFound}/>
</Route>
```

Inside `EnsureAuthHandler` I want to check if user has access token, if "NO" I would like to redirect him to login, if "YES" children route handler can fire actions to load its' data.

Inside `RegisterHandler` and `LoginHandler` I have forms with several fields. I'm using one `AuthStore` and one `AuthActions` files. On submit I'm firing smth like `AuthActions.register(formData)` and if submit fails form component gets errors to `state` from `AuthStore` but if no errors happen I redirect user to `Dashboard`.

I'm feeling like it's a bit overcomplicated? For example using stores to save errors of login/register.

Another point, how to intercept unauthorized API error in one place, `addListener` to Flux dispatcher?

Comment: check out [este](https://github.com/este/este) React/Flux dev stack and starter kit. It has a login and signup component.

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback function in React.run point of your application:

```
// Defaults to `Router.HashLocation`
// callback is called whenever the hash changes
Router.run(routes, callback);

// HTML5 History
// callback is called when history events happen
Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, callback);

// Server rendering
// callback is called once, immediately.
Router.run(routes, '/some/path', callback);
```

Which receives two arguments:

1. Root
2. state

**Root** -
A ReactComponent class with the current match all wrapped up inside it, ready for you to render.

**state** -
An object containing the matched state.

Just go to
http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Router.run